# Lost animation marker after hide marker google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I set animation BOUNCE for marker. When i click button hide to hide marker. After i click button show to show marker, it has not animation before.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</script>
</head>
<script>
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0394475,105.7540192);
    var marker;
    function initialize(){
        var mapProp = {
          center:latlng,
          zoom:14,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            position: latlng,
            animation : google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    $(function(){
        $('#btn1').click(function(){
            marker.setVisible(false);
            console.log('hide animating = ' + marker.animating);
            console.log('hide animation = ' + marker.animation);
        });

        $('#btn2').click(function(){
            marker.setVisible(true);
            console.log('show animating = ' + marker.animating);
            console.log('show animation = ' + marker.animation);
        });
    })  
</script>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width:700px;height:480px;"></div>
<button id="btn1">Hide</button>
<button id="btn2">show</button>
```

I debug marker has attribute animation :
[image: Wath animation marker]
And :
[image: Show log animation marker]
I can set animation : **google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE** again in function click of button show. But i want to know why marker lost animation after click button ?

Comment: The behaviour to stop a marker's animation if the marker's visibility changes is defined in the API itself, although it's not documented. What you're seeing is normal behaviour.

Comment: Oh. I think marker has  still existed value animation so marker will return old state. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `visible` property doesn't seem to change the animation, although toggling it does stop animation.  If you want to use the existing animation property, you can restart the animation with:

```
  $('#btn2').click(function() {
    marker.setVisible(true);
    if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
      marker.setAnimation(marker.getAnimation());
    }
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ov7hyqbm/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    position: latlng,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    marker.setVisible(false);
    console.log('hide animating = ' + marker.animating);
    console.log('hide animation = ' + marker.animation);
  });

  $('#btn2').click(function() {
    marker.setVisible(true);
    console.log(marker.getAnimation());
    if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
      marker.setAnimation(marker.getAnimation());
    }
    console.log('show animating = ' + marker.animating);
    console.log('show animation = ' + marker.animation);
  });
})
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0394475, 105.7540192);
var marker;
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Hide</button>
<button id="btn2">show</button>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Not working if animation is google.maps.Animation.DROP

Comment: What do you expect it to do? It drops when it is added to the map, do you expect it to drop again?  That is a different problem.

Comment: Expected drop animation on setVisible ;) But found another way.

Answer (score 0):

For the button that re-activates the marker you could explicitly call the `setAnimation` method

```
    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        marker.setVisible( true );
        marker.setAnimation( google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE );

        console.log('show animating = ' + marker.animating);
        console.log('show animation = ' + marker.animation);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that. I want to know detail about marker